# Scripting with unix to get the processes run by users

Tags: linux, bash, unix

If I find out I have two users logged (UserA and UserB) in to the systems right now, How do i find out the processes run by those two users. but, the trick here is the script is to be run in an unattended batch without any input from the keyboard. other than being invoked.

I know the first part of the script would be 
who | awk '{print $1}'
the output of this would be 
UserA
UserB

What I would like to know is, how can I use this output and shove it with some ps command automatically and get the required result.

Comment: Do you have any failed attempts at using the `ps` command to do this?

Comment: No, i am not sure how to put the out of the who command to ps command to get the processes run by those users currently logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the one-liner I was searching for, with the help of the other answers (**updated** for case where no users logged in - see comments).

```
ps -fU "`who | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq | xargs echo`" 2> /dev/null
```

The thing inside the backticks is executed and "inserted at the spot". It works as follows:

```
who             : you know what that does
cut -d' '       : split strings into fields, using ' ' as separator
-f1             : and return only field 1
uniq            : return only unique entries
xargs echo      : take each of the values piped in, and send them through echo: this strips the \n
2> /dev/null    : if there are any error messages (sent to 2: stderr)
                : redirect those to /dev/null - i.e. "dump them, never to be seen again"
```

The output of all that is

```
user1 user2 user3
```

...however many there are. And you then call `ps` with the `-fU` flags, requesting all processes for these users with full format (you can of course change these flags to get the formatting you want, just keep the `-U` in there just before the thing in "`  `"

```
ps -fU user1 user2 user3
```

Comment: +1  Well, I do like the style.  This was originally my approach, but I didn't like how *ps(1)* errored out when no one was logged in.

Comment: @pilcrow thanks. The question did start with "two users logged in" so I had honestly not considered what happens if `who` returned nothing. The saving grace is the fact that the error message goes to `stderr` - so you can add `2> /dev/null` at the end and error message is suppressed...

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of users (using who), save to a file, then list all processes, and grep that (using the file you just created),

```
tempfile=/tmp/wholist.$$
who | cut -f1 -d' '|sort -u > $tempfile
ps -ef |grep -f $tempfile
rm $tempfile
```

Comment: I thought of this solution, but had been banging my head against a wall trying to do this without a temp file... Clearly "just make it work" was the right approach. But out of curiosity- can you get this to work (maybe with `xargs`) without a temp file?

Comment: @Floris, yes — you can also get it to work without grep.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
LOGGED_IN=$( who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | xargs echo )

[ "$LOGGED_IN" ] && ps -fU "$LOGGED_IN"
```

The [standard switch `-U`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/ps.html)  will restrict output to only those processes whose real user ID corresponds to any given as its argument.  (E.g., ps -f -U "UserA UserB".)

Comment: Your answer inspired me for the one-liner I came up with - "just because I had to". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but you can pipe the output of ps through grep to get the processes run by a particular user, like so:

```
ps -ef | grep '^xxxxx '
```

where xxxxx is the user.

Comment: how can i make it happen automatically without me entering the user IDs of the people currently logged in. so, the out of the who command should go to the ps command automatically and give the required result. How can i do that?